# Laravel - Count registrations status per event

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Struggling with relationships - Using Laravel 5.4, I have three tables

- event

  - **id**
  - name
  - other fields..
- registration

  - id
  - **event_id**
  - **status_id**
  - other fields...
- status

  - **id**
  - name
  - other fields...

**Status Model**

```
public function registrations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Registration::class);
    }
```

**Event Model**

```
public function registrations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Registration::class);
    }
```

**Registration Model**

```
public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class, 'event_id');
    }
```

and my EventsController looks like this

```
public function findRegistrations($id)
    {
        $viewEvent = Event::find($id)->registrations;
        return view('events.details', compact('viewEvent'));

    }
```

I just need to **count** the number of statuses as per the event, because I have different statuses

- New
- Reviewed
- Approved
- Rejected

  and I need to display each status number on blade template, for example
- New (5)
- Reviewed (9)
- Approved (4)
- Rejected (10)

how do I accomplish that using Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm answering my own question with the help of thiout, thanks for giving hints.

Here is the solution:

```
$status = Status::select([
        'statuses.id',
        'statuses.statusName',
        \DB::raw('count(registration.status_id) as count')
    ])->join('registration','registration.status_id','=','statuses.id')
        ->where('event_id', '=', $id)
        ->groupBy('registration.status_id')
        ->get();
    return $status;
```

I hope it helps someone else!

**Results**

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   statusName: "NEW",
   count: 10
  },
 {
  id: 2,
  statusName: "REVIEWED",
  count: 14
 },
 {
 id: 3,
 statusName: "APPROVED",
 count: 12
 },
 {
 id: 4,
 statusName: "REJECTED",
 count: 3
 }
]
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You could use DB like

add this on top of your EventsController :

```
use DB;
```

then something like :

```
public function getStatusForEvent($id)
{
    $status = DB::table('status')
        ->join('registrations', 'registrations.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
        ->where('registrations.event_id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return $status;

}
```

Comment: How do I count the number of status as per that event??

Comment: If each registration has a status then just count the number of registrations, if not return count($status) from my function

Comment: But the thing is, status might be different for each. I have 4 types of status - New, Reviewed, Accepted, Rejected. I need to get the number of each and display that number as per the event

Comment: I would try  $status = DB::table('status')
        ->join('registrations', 'registrations.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
        ->where('registrations.event_id', '=', $id)->groupBy('status_label')
        ->get(); replacing your status_label by the label of the corresponding column in the status object model

Comment: Dosen't work, returns error  - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'quickstartagain.statuses.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Even when I put the strict mode to false, it does not produce the results that that I am looking for, I need a way to get all the statuses from status table and join, then count the registrations.status_id and have it displayed as I've written in my question. New (N), Reviewed (N) ...etc